# How to adjust spacing between list items in MediaWiki?

Tags: css, format, mediawiki

In the MediaWiki that I host, unordered lists have awkward spacing, particularly between items at different levels.  You can see this in the image below where the vertical spacing between a second level item (Banana) and its parent (Apple) is larger than that between the the second level item and the proceeding item (Orange).

[image: Example of list format.]

So far, I've tried adding some CSS to MediaWiki:Common.css to correct the issue.  I'm no CSS expert, so it's mostly trial and error.  My best guess was that the margin-top of ul is set too large, so I tried adding the following CSS:

```
li { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
ul { padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px; }
```

Unfortunately, this didn't seem to help.  How can I remove this additional spacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to use "line-height" in the css

li{line-height:16px;}

or you can use debugging tool of chrome to know weather it is padding or margin

Comment: Using Chrome's inspect tool was a good suggestion.  For the ul in question, Chrome seems to indicate that the following style is overriding the style I provided in Common.css:

    .mw-content-ltr ul, .mw-content-rtl .mw-content-ltr ul {
        margin: 0.3em 0 0 1.6em;
        padding: 0;
    }

Comment: use !important with your style 

ul { padding-top: 0px !important; margin-top: 0px !important; }

Comment: Adding the !important tags fixed it!  Thanks!